# best practice to select and modify entries in nested vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm looking for an efficient way to solve the following (presumably easy) problem:

- I have a vector of type `A`.
- Class `A` contains a vector of type `B`.
- There is no way that I can change class `A` or the design of
  the vector of class `A` (I cannot make it a vector of pointers to `A`
  for example).

I want to have a vector of class `B` which contains all entries of `B` contained in the vector of `A` with a special attribute.

I guess it is a bit complicated to read about the problem but probably easier to understand if you see an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B {
  int n;
  double val;
};

struct A {
  vector<B> v;
};

int main() {
  // generate some dummy data:
  A a1;
  a1.v.push_back(B{1, 1.0});
  a1.v.push_back(B{2, 2.0});
  a1.v.push_back(B{1, 3.5});

  A a2;
  a1.v.push_back(B{2, 2.0});
  a1.v.push_back(B{3, 1.0});
  a1.v.push_back(B{1, 2.5});

  // this is my initial situation: a vector of type A
  vector<A> va;
  va.push_back(a1);
  va.push_back(a2);

  // what I want to get is a vector of type B with all B values whose n == 1
  vector<B> vb;

  // possible solution to get all elements of B
  for(auto &any : va){
    for(auto &b : any.v){
      if(b.n == 1){
        vb.push_back(b);
      }
    }
  }

  for(const auto &any:vb){
    cout << any.val << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

I would like to get the vector of class `B` without copying every element. Later, I need to modify the elements in vector `B` and they should also be modified in vector `A` (meaning, if I change `vb[0].val = 100;` the entry in `va[0].v[0]` should also be `100`;

I thought about using pointers to do this but I am unsure if it is a good idea since the elements of vector `va` are allocated on the stack and not on the heap.

** Edit: **

I can ensure that as soon as I need the vector of `B` I will not modify the vector of `A` in any way.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot avoid copying. C++ does not work this way. You can, maybe, create a vector of `std::reference_wrapper`s, and perhaps accomplish something similar to that, but, as far as having a vector of `B`s, there's no way to avoid copying. This is, perhaps, how objects work in Java, but C++ is not Java.

Comment: "since the elements of vector va are allocated on the stack and not on the heap. " vectors elements are never on the stack. Maybe thats your misunderstanding: after `va.push_back(a1);` the vector contains a copy of `a1` but not `a1` itself

Comment: In addition to @idclev463035818's comment: It doesn't matter what an object's storage class is when you use non-owning pointers. They can always be used.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you, I thought there is no way around but wanted to make sure

Comment: ...but consider that pointers to elements are not stable. Ie they get invalidated if you add/remove something to/from the vector

Comment: @idclev463035818 that was my fear as well

Comment: Yes, @user7431005: The question is whether or not you can guarantee that the vectors in the `A`s and `vector<A>` are not modified (elements added or removed) while you use `vb`.

Comment: I dont understand your question fully, but some more pointers: there are containers that have stable iterators/pointers to elements, eg `std::list`. Also if you never do something that invalidates iterators, storing iterators into a vector can be fine.

Comment: *Later, I need to modify the elements in vector B and they should also be modified in vector A* Why don't you just do `for(auto &any : va){
    for(auto &b : any.v){
      if(b.n == 1){
        do thing here
      }
    }
  }` when you need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `va` on the stack is not necessarily a problem, as long as you move `va` to its new location. In that case your "moved to" vector will internally point to the storage allocated by your "moved from" `va` vector (and the original `va` will become empty).

What is an issue though, is if you add new `B`s to an `A` after having already created pointers to `B`s. If the `A`'s `v` vector does not have enough capacity to store the newly inserted `B`, it will have to reallocate all its `B` elements to a new storage location. That in turn will change the addresses of all of those `B` elements.

Thus, you are fine to create pointers as long as you can guarantee that:

- `va` is moved instead of copied.
- No new `B`s are added to an `A` after initialization.

Assuming the above can be guaranteed, you can create your `vb` as follows:

```
std::vector<B *> vb;

for (auto & a : va) {
  for (auto & b : a.v) {
    if (b.n == 1) { vb.push_back(&b); }
  }
}
```

or using `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<B>> vb;

for (auto & a : va) {
  std::copy_if(a.v.begin(), a.v.end(),
    std::back_inserter(vb),
    [](auto const & b) { return b.n == 1; });
}
```

Comment: nitpick, using std::for_each with std::copy_if would have made this perfect.

Comment: Personally I prefer the ranged for here.  Looks cleaner IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I can make sure that I will not modify `va` anymore as soon as I need `vb`

Comment: @theWiseBro I personally feel `std::for_each` wouldn't add any extra readability here over using a range-based for-loop, but I understand why you'd want to use it here.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be completely clear that moving the vector doesn't invalid iterators, see [LWG issue 2321](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321) (and it certain does invalidate if `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` of the allocator is `false`).

Comment: @walnut Hm, I can see how that might be an issue with some custom allocator. But would this ever be a problem with a "standard" `std::vector`? Also, would `pointer to element` and `iterator` be considered equivalent here? E.g. an iterator containing a pointer to vector + index would break, whereas one containing a pointer to element might not.

Comment: @Darhuuk I am not saying that it is likely to be a problem in practice with the common standard library implementations, just that the standard isn't entirely clear on whether iterator (or references or pointers) to elements *may* be invalidated. I agree that it is probably not reasonably for pointers and references to be invalidated with the default allocator. I kind of blanked on the code not requiring iterators to be stable, sorry.